# Migrated from ASP.NET to .NET Core and my API is now very slow. What can I do to diagnose?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I just migrated a pretty old API (development was started in early 2000s)to .Net Core. I'm not super comfortable in the environment but I managed to get it working ok and it seems like it's way easier to do simple things like set up CORS/Http Verb Routing etc. My only issue is that the requests will occasionally take a really long time to complete. (eg. 50 seconds) whereas before it would have been quick.

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong because it won't happen to the same request every time and sometimes it works perfectly fine. Does anyone have any recommendations on how I can diagnose what is holding up the API response?

Here is a log from the requests:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:44374/APIAllitem/Getitems/48/9766696088310E6D3C15227DE232D2?ckey=1575572795915 application/json 368
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "Getitems", controller = "APIAllitem"}. Executing action MyProject.Controllers.APIAllitemController.Getitems (MyProject)
// Log pauses here for the long 'wait'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method MyProject.Controllers.APIAllitemController.Getitems (MyProject) with arguments (48, 9766696088310E6D3C15227DE232D2, MyProject.Controllers.APIAllitemController+GetitemsParams) - Validation state: Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action method MyProject.Controllers.APIAllitemController.Getitems (MyProject), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult in 448.3576ms.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor:Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action MyProject.Controllers.APIAllitemController.Getitems (MyProject) in 26134.6832ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 26143.0763ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

You can see that this particular request took 26 seconds to complete.

This is what that controller action looks like currently:

```
// Just for passing body params into the action
public class GetTypesParams {
  public string field;
  public string order;
  public int page;
  public int max;
}

[HttpPost("{id}/{key}")] // <- Matches route APILogTypeListController/GetTypes/{id}/{key}
public IActionResult GetTypes(int id, string key, [FromBody]GetTypesParams bodyParams)
{
    //Controller Logic ......... 
    return StatusCode(200, myResponseJSON);
}
```

And just to compare, this is what then original controller action looked like prior to migrating:

```
public void GetTypes(int id, string key, [FromBody]string field, [FromBody]string order, [FromBody]int page, [FromBody]int max)
{
    //Controller Logic ......... 
    response.Clear();
    response.BufferOutput = false;
    response.StatusCode = 200;
    response.Write(myResponseJSON);
    response.End();
}
```

I don't know if it has anything to do with:

- The new Kestrel Server
- Attribute Routing
- <s>new ObjectResult</s>
- <s>Somehow .Net Core affecting the controller interaction with the database</s> The delay actually occurs before the controller method is even called, so this is not the delay.
- ???

If anyone could give me some insight as to what part of the application might be causing the issue and how I'd be able to debug/look into it futher, I'd greatly appreciate it. Right now I'm going to start on running the controller actions 1 at a time and seeing if changing anything in the request affects anything.

Comment: You need to see if you can make it reproducible - or just capture how long everything takes until you find get a request that shows the symptoms. Profile it. Find exactly how long each bit of it takes. That probably means you're going to need to log data, and/or look at profiling tools. We really can't help you much more than that. It's up to you to investigate and narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio for development, there are quite a few option, including Application Insights.

Comment: You're asking for help diagnosing the issue, yet you've redacted everything that's causing the issue, i.e. `//Controller Logic...`. As such, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks, I discovered that the controller methods are actually not even getting called until the end of the long wait, ie. after the methods are called it runs instantly and returns a response to the browser. It must be something prior to the controller action method.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Thanks, I was looking for recommendations of how to potentially find a solution, since I know that its near impossible for anyone to just know off the top of their head what's wrong without very much to look through.

Comment: interesting, what does this argument come from?  9766696088310E6D3C15227DE232D2

Comment: Between those log entries is Controller creation & DI, model binding, model validation... If your model is complex and can contain circular references, validation can take a *long* (but not infinite) time.

Comment: @TheMikeInNYC it's a temporary API key that is generated on the server, stored on the client's localstorage, and passed into each API call.

Comment: My case was NLog without async in targets:
<target async="true">

I would recommend others having the same problem to verify your log configurations.

Comment: @GuilhermeMuniz Thank you very much. You saved my day. This should an accepted answer if you use NLOG